# How can i improve my javascript? codepen included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this code pen on my website for a menu button in mobile view: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNNaYp

Sometimes the button breaks when it is spam clicked ie. the 'X' state would appear when the menu is closed.

Anyway i want to know how i could improve my javascript because i know i could do it using jQuery, i've tried but failed.

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="showcase"><button type="button" role="button" aria-label="Toggle Navigation" id="buttonOne" class="lines-button x2">
<span class="lines"></span>
</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #5DC1AF;
}

.showcase {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.lines-button {
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 0.57143rem;
}

/*.lines-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}*/

.lines-button:active {
  transition: 0;
}

.lines {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 0.37143rem;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: 0.28571rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}

.lines:before,
.lines:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 0.37143rem;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  border-radius: 0.28571rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0.28571rem center;
  transform-origin: 0.28571rem center;
}

.lines:before {
  top: 1rem;
}

.lines:after {
  top: -1rem;
}

/*.lines-button:hover .lines:before {
  top: 1.14286rem;
}

.lines-button:hover .lines:after {
  top: -1.14286rem;
}*/

.lines-button.close {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
  transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1em;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

button span {
  display: block;
}

.lines-button.x2 .lines {
  transition: background 0.3s 0.5s ease;
}

.lines-button.x2 .lines:before,
.lines-button.x2 .lines:after {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: top 0.3s 0.6s ease, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease;
  transition: top 0.3s 0.6s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
}

.lines-button.x2.close .lines {
  transition: background 0.3s 0s ease;
  background: transparent;
}

.lines-button.x2.close .lines:before,
.lines-button.x2.close .lines:after {
  transition: top 0.3s ease, -webkit-transform 0.3s 0.5s ease;
  transition: top 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s 0.5s ease;
  top: 0;
  width: 4rem;
}

.lines-button.x2.close .lines:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 45deg);
}

.lines-button.x2.close .lines:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg);
}

button:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
```

JS

```
var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('button');

[].forEach.call(anchor, function(anchor) {
  var open = false;
  anchor.onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!open) {
      this.classList.add('close');
      open = true;
    } else {
      this.classList.remove('close');
      open = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to achive? the codepen works fine at my place

Comment: Can not reproduce anything breaking

Comment: @Gho5t you should cite sources or not make guesses

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is for improvements of working code; StackOverflow is for improving broken code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about **non**-functioning code. This is more approriate for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) **but** check their guidelines first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[View in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45b4f7c8/1/)

Use following jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("close");
  });
});
```